# JDatePicker prevent user from selecting date when disable

Tags: java, swing

I have implemented a JDatePicker using the following code:

```
 final UtilDateModel expiryDateModel = new UtilDateModel();

                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.put("text.today", "Today");
                prop.put("text.month", "Month");
                prop.put("text.year", "Year");

                final JDatePanelImpl expiryDatePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(expiryDateModel, prop);

                final JDatePickerImpl expiryDatePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(expiryDatePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
```

I have tried doing expiryDatePicker.setEnabled(false) but it does not seem to disable it as user can still select the date. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 6):

I have had the same Problem, I finally found a simple solution:

first get your JDatePickerImplementer object, call it:      datePickerImpl

**datePickerImpl.getComponent(1).setEnabled(false);**